# Python how to read 2nd column from 3rd row in csv file

Tags: python, file, csv

I have to parse a csv file and the first useful information in the file lies in 3rd row and second column.

Here's a snippet of what I did so far:

```
f = open(filename, r)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimeter=';')
i=0
for row in reader:
    if (i == 2):
        useful_data  = row[2]
        break
    else:
        i += 1
```

but I don't like this approach. Can any one suggest a better approach?

Comment: Must you use python ? There are simpler ways to do it using awk , sed etc.

Comment: @Gautam not if the csv is multi-line, has quotes, spaces in the values ...

Comment: note that the snippet has typos: r => "r" and `delimeter` => `delimiter`

Comment: yes i must use python, the software is written in python.

Comment: How is your solution deficient?  What are you trying to improve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itertools.islice` can make things short here:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    useful_data = next(islice(reader, 2, None))[2]
```

Comment: Thanks for understanding. BTW, I think it would be clearer/more useful to give names to the hardcoded constants you have for the row and column values: i.e. `next(islice(reader, row+1, None))[column]`. Also, in Python 3, csv files should be `open`ed with a `newline=''` keyword argument.

Comment: @martineau agree about the constants

Comment: Not quite. When I try using `'rb'` instead of `newline=''` I get a `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`.

Comment: Whether it "works" without the `newline` will depend on whether the csv file has fields in it with newline characters embedded in them. For generality, using `newline` would make it work regardless—and is therefore better/more correct in my opinion because it makes fewer assumptions about the nature of the data being read.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `for` loop then `break`, use manual iteration on the file with `next`

Just skip as many lines as you wish using `next` on the csv reader, then use `next` one last time and pick the column you want:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    # skip 2 rows
    for _ in range(2):
        next(reader)

    useful_data = next(reader)[2]
```

Comment: I like your solution but is can we somehow get rid of the for loop ?

Comment: for 2 rows to skip, yes, you can call `next(reader)` twice :)

Comment: haha.. nice one there ;)

Comment: there's a good solution using `islice`, check it out. it uses a loop but at least it's not a python loop

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you dislike about it? I think a slightly nicer version would be:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 2:
            useful_data = row[2]
            break
```

Comment: your code has still the same typos as OP attempt

Comment: I dislike the if else statement and a for loop just for reaching a specific line. I was hoping to get something like what @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fabre below posted but without a for loop

Comment: Yes, Jean-François, copy-pasted some errors in the first place. @gajendra: Thanks for the clarification.